# Spring MVC CSS, fonts, images wont show in index.html page

Tags: java, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring framework and I was able to run my index.html from my localhost but all resources won't show.  Below is my folder structure

```
- src/main
    - webapp
        - resources
            - css (All css files)
            - fonts (All font files)
            - images (All image files)
            - js (All js files)
        - static
            - index.html (my index.html)
        - WEB-INF
```

My index.html page:

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My First Application</title>

    <meta name="description" content="overview &amp; stats" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- bootstrap & fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    .........
```

In the "href"  I tried changing the directory path multiple times, the page is loading but just a bunch of texts (No css, image, etc)

Do I also need to update my servlet-context.xml or web.xml?

EDIT:

I checked servlet-context.xml and the mapping already exists for resoucres:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

I even added:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/css" location="/resources/css" />
<resources mapping="/resources/fonts" location="/resources/fonts" />
<resources mapping="/resources/images" location="/resources/images" />
```

but still won't work.

EDIT 2:

When I go to chrome - inspect - console.  This is the log:

```
springmvc:13 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css 
springmvc:21 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/ace.min.css 
springmvc:18 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/fonts.googleapis.com.css 
springmvc:26 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/ace-skins.min.css 
springmvc:27 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/ace-rtl.min.css 
springmvc:36 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/ace-extra.min.js 
springmvc:2149 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js 
springmvc:2159 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js 
springmvc:2166 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js 
springmvc:2167 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js 
springmvc:2168 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js 
springmvc:2169 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery.sparkline.index.min.js 
springmvc:2170 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery.flot.min.js 
springmvc:2171 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery.flot.pie.min.js 
springmvc:2172 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery.flot.resize.min.js 
springmvc:12 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css 
springmvc:18 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/fonts.googleapis.com.css 
springmvc:13 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css 
springmvc:21 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/ace.min.css 
springmvc:26 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/ace-skins.min.css 
springmvc:27 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/css/ace-rtl.min.css 
springmvc:36 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/ace-extra.min.js 
springmvc:2149 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js 
springmvc:2159 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js 
springmvc:2166 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js 
springmvc:2167 GET http://localhost:8080/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js 
springmvc:2180 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at springmvc:2180
```

Basically, all the lines in my html that has the:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=
```

Throws an error.

I tried to change the "href" to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/ace-skins.min.css" />
```

But still the same, css, images, etc won't load.

Comment: have you added any resource handler mapping ? kindly disclose your app container details!

Comment: sorry, new to using spring framework, what do you mean by app container details?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register **Resource Handler** in spring to `serve static content` you can do it by `XML way` as 
 or

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

`Java config`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }
}
```

you can also add multiple resource location as

```
.addResourceLocations("/resources/","classpath:/other-resources/");
```

use commat to delimit the string and you can provide as many resource location as you want!

**Enjoy coding!**

Comment: I checked in xml and the mapping already exists. question updated.

Comment: not sure what you mean but i got this error in network "<img src="/timesheet/src/main/webapp/resources/images/avatars/avatar3.png" class="msg-photo" alt="Susan's Avatar" />" = "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: kindly update your question with whole html if possible or some interesting part of it like above one! and I would like to know your deployed application path on the tomcat! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative links like below. Also use Thymeleaf's th:href

```
<link rel="s`tylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
href="../../../resources/css/styles.css"` 
th:href="@{/resources/css/styles.css}" />
```

See your deployed directory structure and ensure required files are present in said folders (resources)

Remember to change the relative path ../../ to correct level.

If files not being copied to /resources folder then trying putting them in /main/src/webapp/resources